# oracle trigger to update row

Tags: oracle, triggers

I've got the following trigger:

```
create or replace 
trigger updateBeds
  After insert or update on INPATIENT_STAY for
    each row
Begin
if(:new.INPATIENT_STAY.DATEPLACEDINWARD<=sysdate and :new.INPATIENT_STAY.expectedleavedate>=sysdate)
then 
  update WARD
    set BEDSAVAIL = TOTALBEDS - 1
    where WARDNUM = :new.INPATIENT_STAY.WARDNUM;
end if;
if(:new.INPATIENT_STAY.DATELEFT <= sysdate) then
  update WARD
    set BEDSAVAIL = TOTALBEDS +1
    where WARDNUM = :new.INPATIENT_STAY.WARDNUM;
end if;
END;
```

This trigger is meant to subtract 1 from the column `totalbeds` if the `INPATIENT_STAY.DATEPLACEDINWARD` and the `INPATIENT_STAY.expectedleavedate` is less than the system date.
Also, if the `INPATIENT_STAY.DATELEFT` is less than or equal to the system date, the `totalbeds` should increase by 1.
`WARD` is linked to `INPATIENT_STAY` by a foreign key in `INPATIENT_STAY` called `WARDNUM`

When i try to compile the trigger, i get the following errors:

```
Error(2,4): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.INPATIENT_STAY'
Error(2,54): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.INPATIENT_STAY'
Error(6,21): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.INPATIENT_STAY'
Error(8,4): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.INPATIENT_STAY'
Error(11,21): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.INPATIENT_STAY'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. any help is much appreciated

The tables are:

```
 WARD
    WARDNUM VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
    NAME VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
    TOTALBEDS NUMBER
    BEDSAVAIL NUMBER

INPATIENT_STAY
   INPATIENTID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   WARDNUM VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   EXPECTEDLEAVEDATE DATE
   DATEPLACEDINWARD DATE
   DATELEFT DATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access columns' values from the inserted/updated row, just use `:new.column_name` - you shouldn't add the table name between the `:new` and column name, try this:

```
create or replace 
trigger updateBeds
  After insert or update on INPATIENT_STAY for
    each row
Begin
if(:new.DATEPLACEDINWARD<=sysdate and :new.expectedleavedate>=sysdate)
then 
  update WARD
    set BEDSAVAIL = TOTALBEDS - 1
    where WARDNUM = :new.WARDNUM;
end if;
if(:new.DATELEFT <= sysdate) then
  update WARD
    set BEDSAVAIL = TOTALBEDS +1
    where WARDNUM = :new.WARDNUM;
end if;
END;
```

Comment: @Pindo Please update your question and show us the table definitions of both `INPATIENT_STAY` and `WARD` tables.

Comment: one of the columns had an incorrect name on my side. thanks!! this worked perfectly